# @graphql-codegen settings for generating objects with type fields

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-js

Are there any `@graphql-codegen` settings for generating similar constants for types from the schema?

```
export declare const Item: {
    readonly Id: "id";
    readonly CreatedBy: "createdBy";
    readonly CreatedDate: "createdDate";
}
```

I tried to find some settings, but so far no results